# Use Django templates to generate forms

Tags: django, django-templates

I’m planning to use the Django templating system in a slightly uncommon way. I need an app that will let me easily create simple “fill in the gap”-style forms and I decided to use Django templates with custom tags to design the forms.

Here is a sketch of what I mean:

```
<p>
This is the <i>form</i>. Two plus two is {% gap four 4 vier %}.<br>
The best programming language is {% case_gap Python Haskell %}.
</p>

{% if all_correct %}
    You are smart.
{% else %}
    <input type="submit">
{% endif %}
```

The idea is that the `*gap` tags render a text input control, look into the context to see if the answer for them was sent, and if the answer is correct, mark the text inputs green.

The question is how to implement the `all_correct` logic. The simple solution is to add this variable to the context and then make each `*gap` tag update it based on its correct answer, and, I believe, this should work with my example. But what if I want to move the `{% if all_correct %}` code to the top of the template, where none of the `gaps` were rendered, and thus none of them have validated their answers yet?

Looks like I need some way to iterate over all the `*gap` tags before starting to render the template and [ask them to] validate the answers, but I don’t know the internals of the templating system well enough to implement this. Or there might be a completely different and better way.

Comment: I think you're trying to do too much in Django templates. The typical approach in Django would be to use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#working-with-forms) to do the validation in the view, then display the results in the template. You might be able to do what you want by diving into the Django template internals, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @Alasdair Well, technically, you are right. But Django forms are too complicated to create the forms I need. Basically, I need a nice language for describing simple forms and I thought that instead of inventing and implementing something new, I could hack the existing one.

Comment: @kirelagin imo, this really isn't that difficult of a use case to handle with Django forms. All forms have a prefix to avoid name collision on fields, and if you were to use a factory pattern to construct a list of forms, you could easily populate the view (and template) with as many forms as necessary for the survey. You can also validate all of the forms in a loop. If all are valid, display your message.

Comment: Of course, my comment makes some assumptions about your model structure, just thinking out loud.

Comment: Well, actually, I want to make creation of forms as simple as possible. In case of Django forms creation of a form requires a model structure and some code written. If I manage to do what I’m thinking about, creating of a form will be as easy as writing this template.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured how to do this after reading [Chapter 9](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09.html) of The Django Book.

Creating of a custom template tag involves defining of two things: how to compile the tag and how to render it. The compile-function should parse the tag data and return a `Node`—basically a thing that has a `.render(self, context)` method and some other data derived from the tag text.

The solution is to create `FormNode`—a subclass of `Node` that will also have a `.validate(self, context)` method. Then our custom tag will be compiled to a subclass of `FormNode` that implements validation logic.

The next thing to do is to create `FormTemplate`—a subclass of `Template` with a super-power: before starting to render individual nodes it will validate all the nodes by iterating over them and calling `validate(context)` on all the subclasses of `FormNode` and it will set the `all_valid` variable in the context.

---

Here is my proof-of-concept implementation: https://github.com/kirelagin/django-template-forms. I believe it works pretty well.

I used the ability to instantiate a custom template engine, which was added in Django 1.8. Overall, I had to dig a little deeper than one might expect and I always had this feeling that splitting of the templating API and the django engine (which is now just one of the available backends) wasn’t complete yet. I hope that Django 2.0 will bring us new cool stuff and all the hacks I had to add will vanish.